# How can I prove the result $\int^a_{-a} f(x) dx = \int^a_0 f(x) + f(-x) dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Suppose $f: [-a, a] \subset \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb C$.

How can I prove the result $$\int^a_{-a} f(x) dx = \int^a_0 f(x) + f(-x) dx$$ ? I'm aware, that if I prove the result in the real case, then I can extend the result to the complex case, since I can write $f(x) = u(x) + i v(x)$ ?

Does the result also holds if we set the domain of $f$ to $(-\infty, \infty), (-\infty, a]$ or $[a, \infty)$ ?

Comment: Assumptions on f?

Comment: I don't really know. I've seen the result used here on this page. I guess we can assume it is continuous for the integral to exist ? Otherwise is it enough to assume the integral exist ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  Evaluate
$$\int_{-a}^0 f(t)\,dt$$
by substituting $x=-t$.

Re: extra questions about domain.

- If the domain is $(-\infty,\infty)$ then the result is still true as long as the integral is still from $-a$ to $a$.  If you want the integral to go from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ then it is an improper integral and you will have to carefully consider convergence.
- If the domain is $(-\infty,a]$ with $a>0$ then the result is still true as long as the integral is from $-a$ to $a$.
- If the domain is $[a,\infty)$ with $a>0$ then $f(x)$ does not make sense for $-a<x<a$, unless you are considering the possibility of analytically extending $f$.